# create a spiral UI bar in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to create a bar like this one in Unity?

[image: Spiral]

The default components seem to work primitive only. I can have a rectangle as a bar or a radial bar.

This spiral bar would need to have access to a path because the color has to know how to move along the sprite.

Comment: I would create different straight bars to achieve this. Like if the total bar has 10 edges, 10 different bars. When one is full, start filling other. But I also like to know if there is an easier way.

Comment: Yes I thought about it, but this "trick" might end in overengineering

Answer (score 5):

I would use a custom shader with a sprite containing the "fill information" as the alpha channel.

On the image below, you will see your original sprite, and an other one with a gradient alpha (sorry, I'm not an expert with photoshop).

[image]

You can download the Unity shaders on [their website](https://unity3d.com/fr/get-unity/download/archive), and pick the **UI-Default.shader** inside *DefaultResourcesExtra/UI* and tweak it a little bit so as to fill the sprite according to the alpha value of the sprite.

Something like this (not tested)

```hlsl
Shader "UI/FillAlpha"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

        _FillAmount ("Fill amount", Float) = 1

        // ...
    }

    SubShader
    {
        // ...

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            fixed _FillAmount;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 color = (tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) + _TextureSampleAdd) * IN.color;

                color.a = color.a > _FillAmount ? 1 : 0 ;

                color.a *= UnityGet2DClipping(IN.worldPosition.xy, _ClipRect);

                // ...

                return color;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you will be able to change the `FillAmount` parameter using [`myMaterial.SetFloat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html)

Comment: If you want to avoid the aliasing issues that will show up with the logical operator "larger than", you should use a function that preserves nuances in the gradient, like: `color.a = saturate((color.a - _FillAmount) * _Transition );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Line Renderer` component to create your bar.
See documentation and examples here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/352/Documentation/Components/class-LineRenderer.html

Note that `Line Renderer` works in a 3D space.